# Receiving data from another server using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, parsing, jsonp

I am trying to send AJAX requests to other servers using jQuery. I am operating locally. If I use HTML dataType I get the classical `Origin http://127.0.0.1 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. So I started using JSONP requests :

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'SomeRemoteServer/SomeFile',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        // do stuff
    },
    error: function(d,msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

The catched error is `parsingerror` and Chrome js debugger outputs `Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html`. After carefully looking for this error on the web I found that the error came from the server and not my script (it should send back MIME type `application/json` or something close to this).

Well it seems however that the server is sending something... I would like to catch the response and self-process the parsing. Is this feasible ? If yes how ? I tried `$.ajax()` option `converters` but without success...

Comment: if the server is outputting text/html then are you sure the server intends you to send a jsonp request to it?

Comment: In my experience, "`Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html`" is a *warning*, not an error. If your code isn't working, there must be something else wrong. (e.g., is the JSONP response from the server a valid script?) A JSONP response is a *script*; it is not JSON (though it may contain JSON in it somewhere) and should not use `application/json`.

Comment: @apsillers : clearly it is not valid. I would like to insert my code before it even check its validity. I would just like to use some regex on the html source code of the url.

Comment: JSONP operates by injecting a new `<script>` tag into the page with the `src` attribute set to the target URL. The JavaScript execution environment cannot read the contents of a resource loaded by a `<script>` tag. Instead, a server that supports JSONP will wrap the response data in a function that gets called when the `<script>` loads. Does this server do that? If it does not, you can't use JSONP. Could you post what the server's response looks like? Se also [What is JSONP all about?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about).

Comment: Thanks for the tips and links. Posted how I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue using `dataFilter`

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'SomeRemoteServer/SomeFile',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    dataFilter: function(data) {
        // will run ok !
    }
    success: function(data) {
        // will fail
    },
    error: function(d,msg) {
        // will result in parsing error
    }
});
```